# How does "GMSActivator.apk" work?

Tags: google-apps, android-x86, remix-os

Android distributions for PC don't come with Google apps installed out of the box because they would need a Google licencing for that. Using those apps requires, according to some sources, a GMSActivator.apk app file or other means of installing Google apps, which are relatively easy to do. My question is how is it possible that it's so easy to bypass Google restrictions and install their apps? I was planning to try Android on my PC but now I'm a little suspicious about that...

Comment: They don't enforce that restriction by law (on end users) or by mechanisms in Android, AFAIK. Android is open after all.